# AWS SES Sending bulk template email returns "The template data is invalid"

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-ses

I'm having a strange problem.

This code appears to be fine, but it returns  "The template data is invalid" every single time.

Am I doing something wrong?

Can it be a Bug?

Thanks

--

MacOS, latest version.

Python 3.6.6

boto3==1.9.57

```
import boto3

verified_email='theemail@examplemail.com'

template_name = "TestTemplateDeleteMe"
template = {
    "TemplateName": template_name,
    "SubjectPart": "Test send bulk template email",
    "HtmlPart": "<h1>Hello {{name}},</h1>Favorite animal is {{favorite_animal}}.",
    "TextPart": "Dear {{name}},\r\nYour favorite animal is {{favorite_animal}}."
}

client = boto3.client('ses', region_name='eu-west-1')

try:
    client.create_template(Template=template)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    try:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] != 'AlreadyExists':
            raise e
    except KeyError:
        raise e

response = client.send_bulk_templated_email(
    Source=verified_email,
    Template='TestTemplateDeleteMe',
    Destinations=[{'Destination': {'ToAddresses': [verified_email]}}],
    DefaultTemplateData='{"name": "TestEmailPerson", "favorite_animal": "TestEmailAnimal"}'
)

print(response)
```

Comment: Actually, the documentation lacks a bit. 
The correct solution to the problem is defined here: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1795

Thanks